# Not able to post the question and there is no reason specified

Tags: discussion, support

I am not able to post a question. When I try to hit the button Post Your Question ,  red color mouseHover appears -

> An error occurred submitting the question.

But there is no reason mentioned regarding the failure of question

My question is not duplicate and in the description I have mentioned code as well as description and HasgTags as JavaScript

What can be wrong?

Just 2 hours before I asked a question and it was answered successfully.

I'm using Google Chrome on windows.

[image]

Console Error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
>   b.scorecardresearch.com/beacon.js:1
>
> Failed to load resource: the> server responded with a status of 503
>   (Service Unavailable)

Comment: Which browser/os are you using? Any errors if you open the console?

Comment: I am using google chrome..how to see the console?

Comment: Hit F12, ctrl+shift+J, or via the menu: Extra > Javascript console

Comment: just edited with the screenshot

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < b.scorecardresearch.com/beacon.js:1
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)

Comment: Question edited with Console error

Comment: Hmmm, if I hit  http://b.scorecardresearch.com/beacon.js it works for me. Are you in a corporate network?

Answer (score 6):

There was a problem when i was adding

< / script> in my code and not specifying it as a code.

I removed some specific parts of code and I am able to post now..

Thanks for suggesting me to look at console

Comment: OK, I guess a dev might have to look at this because I suppose that should not break in this way. Glad you solvd your self though.

Comment: Sounds like an aggressive proxy at your end.